# Unable to create function without .NET Azure Python Function App v2

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm using the Azure CLI (2.0.60) and Azure Function Core Tools (2.7.1505) - both installed using npm on mac - to create a Python 3.6 Function App.

When creating a function with `func new` and selecting a binding template that needs an extension I get the following error

```
1. Azure Blob Storage trigger
2. Azure Cosmos DB trigger
3. Azure Event Grid trigger
4. Azure Event Hub trigger
5. HTTP trigger
6. Azure Queue Storage trigger
7. Azure Service Bus Queue trigger
8. Azure Service Bus Topic trigger
9. Timer trigger
Choose option: 7
Azure Service Bus Queue trigger

The Azure Service Bus Queue trigger template has extensions.
Extensions command requires dotnet on your path.
Please make sure to install dotnet (.NET Core SDK) for your system
from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download
```

However, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#v2) clearly states

> You can bypass the requirement for installing the .NET Core 2.x SDK by using extension bundles.

My `host.json` file is according to the documentation:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    }
}
```

I would like to use Azure Functions without installing .NET. What can I do?

p.s. I verified with my colleagues. They are reporting the same issue with

- Dockerized Ubuntu
- Windows cmd

Comment: cant you just create it in the portal?

Comment: Creation in the portal may be a workaround. It is however not an answer to this question/bug. Also, in general not all developers like portals to do their work in. Which is why the CLI exists in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to manually update/create a function, and then use `func start`. While `func new` has this problem, the `func start` counterpart is perfectly able to handle the extension binding. It appears to be a bug in `func new`.